# How to send an email from Jenkins only in a release?

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

I was trying to resolve this issue, and searching forums etc. and trying for myself, without success.

We have a jenkins job and there we use the *Release Plugin* (with a standard configuration)

[image: release plugin config]

In the job then we have the "Perform Maven Release" in the left side to generate a version (tag, change poms, etc.) This work perfect.

[image: Release button on the left side]

We want to send an email to the team when the release has been done.

I tried the enviroment variable that the release plugin sets (IS_M2RELEASEBUILD by default) and combine with the email-ext plugin plugin where I can attach a groovy script (*advanced=>trigger=>script trigger*)

[image: trigger with the email ext plugin]

And I tried a lot of scripts to active the email, and none works, my last chance was:

```
def env = System.getenv()
env['IS_M2RELEASEBUILD'] == 'true'
```

but when I perform the release we have not the email sent (so this script evaluate the conditional to false or whatever)

Anyone has this setup in his Jenkins?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use "Editable Email Notification" as "Post-build Action" and paste

```
def env = build.getEnvironment();
String isRelease = env['IS_M2RELEASEBUILD'];
logger.println "IS_M2RELEASEBUILD="+isRelease;
if ( isRelease == null || isRelease.equals('false')) {
  logger.println "cancel=true;";
  cancel=true;
}
```

as Pre-send Script, fill in your E-Mail(s) in "Project Recipient List" and add an "Success"-Trigger.
(precondition is you have not changed the default "Release envrionment variable" in "Maven release build")

Comment: And... YES! It works!  +1   I tried a lot of scripts and setups, I don't know why I fail, but actually your script is working now.

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

This plugin allows you to configure every aspect of email notifications. You can customize when an email is sent, who should receive it, and what the email says.

Comment: Thanks. I am using this plugin and using the groovy code I wrote above to "fire" the email. The problem is that I don't know the exact code for the email ext plugin to connect with the release action.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, just a suggestion (I can't add comments). Have you tried echoing that environment variable in a post-build and pre-build step?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having another build run when the release build completes successfully and have that job send the email, perhaps by running a shell script.